# Retrieving an entity instead of persisting it during a request

Tags: symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

I'm using api-platform and I have a Book entity that has a `ManyToOne` relation to a Writer.

All writers are already persisted in the database, so I'd like to be able to create Books with a POST request containing the writer it is bound to.

But it keeps trying to persist a new writer.

How can I achieve that ?

Edit:

**Books**

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\BooksRepository")
 * @ApiResource(
 *     attributes={
 *          "normalization_context"={"groups"={"read"}}
 *      }
 *
 * )
 */
class Books
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Property", inversedBy="beans")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"read"})
     */
    private $property;

    public function getProperty(): ?Property
    {
        return $this->property;
    }

    public function setProperty(?Property $property): self
    {
        $this->property = $property;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Writers** (also called Property)

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PropertyRepository")
 */
class Property
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"read"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=30)
     * @Groups({"read"})
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Books", mappedBy="property", orphanRemoval=true)
     * @Groups({"read"})
     */
    private $books;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->books = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getType(): ?string
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    public function setType(string $type): self
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Books[]
     */
    public function getBooks(): Collection
    {
        return $this->books;
    }

    public function addBook(Books $book): self
    {
        if (!$this->books->contains($book)) {
            $this->books[] = $book;
            $book->setProperty($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeBook(Books $book): self
    {
        if ($this->books->contains($book)) {
            $this->books->removeElement($book);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($book->getProperty() === $this) {
                $book->setProperty(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add to your answer the code that builds the form (or passes the post data) and the code that persist a book with the passed data?

Comment: I added all the code I got, not much since I'm using api-platform and everything is hidden

Answer (score 1):

The following request should do the trick:

```
POST /books

{
  "property": "/writers/1"
}
```